# Delete the node at index i from its current position and insert it after node at index j

Tags: c++, performance, vectors, circular-list

I was trying to create a function to delete the node at index `i` from its current position and insert it after node at index `j` from a `std::vector<Node> nodes`. These container is logically a circular container of nodes, that is there's no actual first or last node, i.e. after `nodes.back()` comes `nodes[0]`.

I really need this function not to have bugs and to be as performant as possible, so I'm asking here your help to a further check and for eventual suggestions to improve its performance.

So, this is the function:

```
/*
 * Delete the node at index i from its current position
 * and insert it after node at index j.
 * */
void SimpleSolution::shift(const int i, const int j) {

    assert_not_out_of_bounds({i, j});

    int x;

    if (j < i) { // ranges [i, end] and [start, j]

        for (x = i; x < nodes.size() - 1; ++x) {
            std::swap(nodes[x], nodes[x + 1]);
        }

        std::swap(nodes[0], nodes.back());

        for (x = 0; x < j; ++x) {
            std::swap(nodes[x], nodes[x + 1]);
        }

    } else { // range [i, j]

        if (i != j) {

            for (x = i; x < j; ++x) {
                std::swap(nodes[x], nodes[x + 1]);
            }

        } else { // i == j

            // i and j are the last elements
            if (i == (nodes.size() - 1)) {
                std::swap(nodes[0], nodes.back());
            } else { // equivalent to std::swap(nodes[i], nodes[i + 1])
                std::swap(nodes[i], nodes[j + 1]);
            }
        }

    }

}
```

I'm not looking for "idiomatic" C++, but for correctness and performance, but if idiomatic also means correctness and performance, then perfect.

Here's the `assert_not_out_of_bounds` method:

```
void SimpleSolution::assert_not_out_of_bounds(const std::initializer_list<int> indices) const {
    for (int i : indices) {
        if (i < 0 || i >= nodes.size()) {
            throw std::out_of_range("i is out of the range");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This looks quite sane, is there a reason you do not work with iterators?

1. your assert doesnt use the reference but a copy, so you should use `const std::initializer_list<int> &indices`
2. In the equal case, i would make it actually explicit and do `std::swap(nodes[i], nodes[i + 1])`, which is the same pattern you used all over the code.
3. It might be ok if your assert is used multiple times, but it is rather confusing, that you pass it i and j and i read only i in the code. Maybe use better names like `index1 index2`
4. Any reason you declare `x` outside of the loops?